# Will reinitializing a JavaScript object at global scope cause a memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, garbage-collection, datatables, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have links in a JQuery DataTable that use JQuery UI's tooltip feature. Each link has a tooltip that is populated by an Ajax call. I would like to limit the number of Ajax calls to as few as possible. The DataTable uses server-side processing, and the results are paginated, so there will never be more than ten links on the page at any one time.

The data that is returned by the Ajax call will never change and thus can be safely cached. In my testing, I have seen that the browser does cache the result of each Ajax call, so that it only makes one call per link, and then uses the cache thereafter. My concern is that some user might have their browser configured in such a way that it doesn't use the cache for some reason, and they will be firing off one Ajax call after another, every time they mouse over a link.

Here is the JavaScript for the tooltip:

```
$('.jobId').tooltip({
    content: function(callback) {
        var jobId = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'myUrl',
            data: {jobId: jobId},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var html = formatResults(data);
                callback(html);
            },
            error: function() {
                callback('An error has occurred.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I considered storing the result of each Ajax call in a JavaScript object declared at global scope, and then checking that before making the Ajax call, but I have the vague sense that this might cause a memory leak somehow.

```
var gJobs = new Object();

$('.jobId').tooltip({
    content: function(callback) {
        var jobId = $(this).text();

        if (gJobs[jobId]) {
            callback(gJobs[jobId]);
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myUrl',
                data: {jobId: jobId},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    var html = formatResults(data);
                    gJobs[jobId] = html;
                    callback(html);
                },
                error: function() {
                    callback('An error has occurred.');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I am also concerned that if the table has a large number of rows, the gJobs object could end up using a lot of memory. To prevent the gJobs object from growing indefinitely, every time the user goes to the next or previous page of results in the DataTable, I use the fnDrawCallback function to reinitialize gJobs:

```
$('#jobsTable').dataTable({
...
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        gJobs = new Object();
    }
});
```

I should mention that since the data returned by each Ajax call doesn't change, I could also just store the data in the JSP as static text, and populate the tooltips that way instead of using Ajax. However, I have to make a separate web service call to get the data for each link, and rather than make ten web service calls every time the user pages forward or back, I would rather load the data on demand via Ajax.

Is there anything wrong with this approach? Is there any way this can cause a memory leak? Should I explicitly delete all the properties of gJobs before reinitializing it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you try for yourself on the chrome profiler?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the Chrome profiler, just wondered if anyone could give a definitive explanation.

Comment: little guide to it if needed http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/chapters/7/challenges/1